# Multiple vmss behind single Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We have multiple background worker vmss that do not need a public IP to work.

I want to be able to connect to arbitrary vm (e.g. to troubleshoot via rdp, or to collect some snapshots using remote profiler etc).

When there's only one VMSS per load balancer all works like a charm. I've setup nat pools for each port used on VMs and all works fine.

Now, if I'm trying to add one more vmss to the same load balancer (using its own nat / backend pools) the deployment fails with

```
Virtual Machine /subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/|providers|Micr
osoft.Compute|virtualMachineScaleSets|...|virtualMachines|0 is using different Availability Set than other Virtual Machines connected to the Load Balancer(s) ...
```

message.

As far as I know there's no way to set up availability set for vmss. Are there any options but keeping own load balancer/public ip for each VMSS?

**UPD** I've found similar scheme for [VM+Availability Set setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internal-overview#intranet-line-of-business-applications) (see ILB endpoint section).

Something like this for VMSS?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't add multiple VMSS to same Load balancer, as a workaround, we can deploy a new VM work as a jumpbox, use this new VM to connect other vmss instances via internal IP addresses, more information please check my answer.

Comment: @Jason Ye - MSFT thanks! Is it possible then to have multiple vmss in same VNet and assign own public api/load balancer for each of it?

Comment: Or create multiple public IP addresses for each load balancer?

Comment: I guess you want to deploy yourself load balancer for those vmss instances, am I right?

Comment: @Jason Ye - MSFT, yep

Comment: Please check my answer,I have update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are right, we **can't** change availability set for vmss.

> if I'm trying to add one more vmss to the same load balancer

As we know, we can't add different availability sets to single load balancer, so we **can't** add one or more VMSS to the same load balancer.

> Are there any options but keeping own load balancer/public ip for each
> VMSS?
>
> We have multiple background worker vmss that do not need a public IP
> to work.

Are those VMss in same VNet?  If yes, we can deploy a new VM in the same Vnet, we can connect to this VM, then use this VM to connect to VMSS instances with internal IP addresses, in this way, this new VM work as a  **jumpbox**. we can use this jumpbox to troubleshoot.

---

**Update**:

> Is it possible then to have multiple vmss in same VNet and assign own
> public api/load balancer for each of it?

Yes, we can create a new Azure VM with public IP, then install **HAproxy** on it, make this VM **work as a load balancer**, add all VMSS instances which in the same Vnet to HAproxy backend pool, in this way, we can access this VM's public IP address + your NAT port to connect VMss instance.

Comment: We can deploy HAproxy in Azure VM, make this VM work as a load balancer, and config NAT rules, in this way, we can connect vmss instances via this public IP address with different ports, please check my answer:)